# Pulling a single value from an array to store in a variable javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I've seen a couple methods of this but they don't seem to work for what I'm looking do to...

I'm using this push for another section of code and I don't see why it would not also work for this one in question.

```
var npc = new Array();

npc.push([  
[5,25,10],
]);

npc.push([  
[18,28,38],
]);

npc.push([  
[1,2,3],
]);
```

I want to set this up so I can call something like...

```
LoadNpc(2);
```

I want it to check the 2nd npc array and set the 3 numbers to variable..

```
hp = 18;
atk = 28;
def = 38;
id = 2;  //current loaded npc's id
```

I'm sure I've been over thinking how to do this and I can't get anything to work correctly. If anyone has a simple javascript to this properly I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks pretty straightforward:

```
var npc = [];
npc.push([5,25,10]);
npc.push([18,28,38]);
npc.push([1,2,3]);

var hp, atk, def, id;

function loadNpc(index){
    id = index;
    hp = npc[index-1][0];
    atk = npc[index-1][1];
    def = npc[index-1][2];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was attempting. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should use array of objects not array of arrays.

```
npc[2] = {hp :18, atk: 28, def :38}
```

You "pull" the values like this:

```
alert(npc[2].atk);
alert(npc[2].hp);
...
```

Comment: Why is that? I would normally using an array of objects. But, whats wrong with the Array of Arrays?

Comment: @limoragni, array is good for multiple entities of one value, object is for multiple values for one "entity".